# Почему в верстке появляется белая полоса снизу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://uzinouzi.github.io/task/index.html

Не могу предоставить самодостаточные, воспроизводимые примеры по той причине, что они возникают именно конкретно в данной верстке и чтобы их сделать как воспроизводимый пример, нужно всю верстку занести сюда, в сниппет.

При адаптации верстки возникли следующие проблемы:

1. Внизу появляется скролл вниз, хотя сама страница вмещается в экран. Просто белая полоса на некоторых экранах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот обычное состояние, но есть скролл вниз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полагаю, что это из-за блока с кругами, но если поставить

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

то это не поможет.
Как можно решить данную проблему?

2. Вторая проблема связана с модальными окнами на странице, когда открываешь модальное окно, `body` задается `overflow: hidden;` скриптом, что бы пользователь не мог скроллить вниз, иначе затемнение пропадает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда кликаешь по вот этой кнопке (Она появляется при узких экранах), то модальное окно появляется вверху страницы, а скролить нельзя

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, 320х480, iPhone4

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, да, это из-за этого круга http://prntscr.com/jmvekj
Но как сделать что бы этот круг скрывался за пределами экрана?, это вообще возможно? Допустим в firefox он работает как надо, скрывается за пределами body, в opera на некоторых телефонах(Там можно выбирать телефоны для проверки адаптива) не скрывается

Comment: на айфоне5 еще интересней. там горизонтальная прокрутка включается

Comment: @eri, да, это из-а этой круговой вещицы, лучше скажите, как пофиксить

Comment: попробуй кружки из дива выкинуть в маин и там позишн-абсолют

Comment: уберите свойство left: 14% с кружка(big-circle)